# Multiple borderColor values for series in Highcharts theme

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts, themes

Since there is a way to define colors in HighCharts theme, for example:

```js
Highcharts.theme = {
    colors: [
        '#ED561B',
        '#DDDF00',
        '#24CBE5',
        '#64E572',
        '#FF9655',
        '#FFF263',
        '#6AF9C4'
    ]
};
```

Is there a way to define multiple borderColor values for series that would match these colors? Something like this:

```js
Highcharts.theme = {
    colors: [
        '#ED561B',
        '#DDDF00',
        '#24CBE5',
        '#64E572',
        '#FF9655',
        '#FFF263',
        '#6AF9C4'
    ],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderColor: [
                 '#cc3333',
                 '#666666'
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

This is the only thing that prevents me from defining adequate theme as I need specific border colors for specific color of a bar. With option like this I wouldn't need to worry about matching styles by copying/pasting style options for each graph I need to make, as Highcharts would apply styles from theme automatically.

Comment: If you think it is good idea to have this functionality in HC, you can ask for it on their uservoice: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api